# LINQ uses extra inner join

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq

Here are my simplified models:

```
public class Resource
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Upgrade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Resource Res { get; set; }
    public int Lvl { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, I need to group by Resource and get [Name] from "Resource" and sum([Amount]) from "Upgrade".
Here is the LINQ:

```
from u in _db.Upgrades
join r in _db.Resources on u.Res equals r
where  u.Lvl > levelFrom
    && u.Lvl <= levelTo
group u by new { r.id, r.Name } into grp
select new UpgradeCost()
{
    resName = grp.Key.Name,
    resAmount = grp.Sum(k => k.Amount),
};
```

And here is the SQL I get (Sqlite):

```
SELECT "r0"."Name" AS "resName", COALESCE(SUM("u"."Amount"), 0) AS "resAmount"
FROM "Upgrades" AS "u"
LEFT JOIN "Resources" AS "r" ON "u"."Resid" = "r"."id"
INNER JOIN "Resources" AS "r0" ON "r"."id" = "r0"."id"
WHERE ("u"."Lvl" > @__levelFrom_0) AND ("u"."Lvl" <= @__levelTo_1)
GROUP BY "r0"."id", "r0"."Name"
```

LINQ uses extra INNER JOIN to group by.
I want it to be made like this:

```
SELECT "r"."Name" AS "resName", COALESCE(SUM("u"."Amount"), 0) AS "resAmount"
FROM "Upgrades" AS "u"
LEFT JOIN "Resources" AS "r" ON "u"."Resid" = "r"."id"
WHERE ("u"."Lvl" > @__levelFrom_0) AND ("u"."Lvl" <= @__levelTo_1)
GROUP BY "r"."id", "r"."Name"
```

Comment: Your second SQL code is the same as the linq code. Where is the problem now?

Comment: You should first fix your class model and LINQ statement by defining and using a navigation property `Resource.Upgrades`. Then you don't need a join nor a grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional join generated when used `u.Res` navigation property. Actually you don't need explicit joins here.

```cs
from u in _db.Upgrades
where  u.Lvl > levelFrom
    && u.Lvl <= levelTo
group u by new { u.Res.id, u.Res.Name } into grp
select new UpgradeCost()
{
    resName = grp.Key.Name,
    resAmount = grp.Sum(k => k.Amount),
};
```

Comment: Oh, I see now! Thanks!